# For iphone dev, do you need to learn cocoa touch?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

For iphone dev, do you need cocoa touch skills or just objective c?

Answer (score 12):

That is like asking: for Java, do you need just Java or also the Java API. Yes, you need to know the language as well as the available libraries. If you already know Objective-C, then you have the requisite knowledge to read and understand the API documentation for the CocoaTouch APIs, but yes, you will need to know (or at least, lookup) and use the CocoaTouch APIs in order to program the iPhone.

P.S. The [iPhoneOS Reference Library](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/navigation/index.html) may be found at the link. You may also find my [Google Custom Search Engine: development/developer/code/coding search](http://sites.google.com/site/michaelsafyan/coding/resources/references/development-search), useful for searching for relavent documentation. For example, here is a search performed for [UINavigationBar](http://www.google.com/custom?hl=en&client=google-coop&cof=FORID%3A13%3BAH%3Aleft%3BCX%3ADevelopment%3BL%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.iconspedia.com%2Fuploads%2F1114806957.png%3BLH%3A100%3BLP%3A1%3BKMBOC%3A%23336699%3B&adkw=AELymgUNZygPVWKVk0-RCcY7c0DPtQXArHUl29JL591SUcMLjmRwg4UpTvqoVHikc7_Y0qEX05BY-ykF9VoQi8byORn_eQrNnOWYmMXZIUyuPQwIN5mU4VCnPD-C06uXCV-LUE1MijOazuqtDl2srlEEBOMtlpMHOzsxHizmfiVJgvuk9Xxmf3AEA8A-50aPFMh5w5mMWTJBbrM-ezGaajT4Zr7A_83F0w&boostcse=0&q=UINavigationBar&btnG=Search&cx=005154715738920500810%3Afmizctlroiw), and another for [UIButton](http://www.google.com/custom?hl=en&client=google-coop&cof=FORID%3A13%3BAH%3Aleft%3BCX%3ADevelopment%3BL%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.iconspedia.com%2Fuploads%2F1114806957.png%3BLH%3A100%3BLP%3A1%3BKMBOC%3A%23336699%3B&adkw=AELymgUNZygPVWKVk0-RCcY7c0DPtQXArHUl29JL591SUcMLjmRwg4UpTvqoVHikc7_Y0qEX05BY-ykF9VoQi8byORn_eQrNnOWYmMXZIUyuPQwIN5mU4VCnPD-C06uXCV-LUE1MijOazuqtDl2srlEEBOMtlpMHOzsxHizmfiVJgvuk9Xxmf3AEA8A-50aPFMh5w5mMWTJBbrM-ezGaajT4Zr7A_83F0w&boostcse=0&q=UIButton&btnG=Search&cx=005154715738920500810%3Afmizctlroiw).

Answer (score 5):

You will need to learn Cocoa Touch, which is a separate library that shares some of the same common ancestry and libraries as full-on Cocoa.

See [here](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/iphone/cocoa-touch.html) for more details.